# ubuntu php_pgsql.dll not found

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu

I installed Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04, with php 5.5.9. I see the Apache screen, the phpinfo screen, but php can't connect to postgresql.

I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()" when I try.

My php.ini acording to 'phpinfo();' is:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

In php.ini I have a [PostgreSQL] section, but no

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

and the file doesn't exist.

The modules loaded include mod_php5, but no *pgsql...

I guess the proxy in my institution has blocked something?

```
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
```

Comment: whats display?
Try this in terminal:
"cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep php_pgsql.dll"

Comment: "php can't connect to postgresql."
whats warning?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post to include the error shown by the browser. But there's no "php_pg" or "php_pgsql.dll" on php.ini.

Comment: @SarDauMort: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()" is this what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

When installing finish

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And check your postgres db connection.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7 it is:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

So, now you can do not uncomment lines in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

DLL's are for windows, do as "Святослав Павленко" mentioned.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```